# Ajax request for PHP loop number

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently trying to get a PHP loop status and update a HTML5 progress bar.
The loop is triggered by a button click and set to 5000 with 1sec sleep() after every execution. I of course also made an Ajax request to which reuqests the current loop number every second and update the progress bar. However the request always waits until the loop is completed and shows me a number like "1234567891011..."

This is my JQuery code which is very simple because it's only for testing and learning purpose

```
function getStatus() {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        data: {request: 'request',},

        success: function( data ) {

            //Call function to update status on the loading bar
            updateBar(data);

        }
    });

    //Update loading bar
    function updateBar(data) {

        $('progress').attr('value', data);
    }
}


function setGo() {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        //async: false,
        data: {status: 'GO',},

        success: function( data ) {}
    });

}


$('#start').click(function(event) { 

    setGo();

    setInterval(function() {

        getStatus();

    }, 1000);

});
```

This is my php Code

```
<?php

//Overwrite php execution limit
set_time_limit(120);

if($_POST['status'] = 'GO') {

    $number = 5000;
    $counter = 0;

    for($i=0; $i != $number; $i++) {

        $counter++;

        sleep(1);

        if(isset($_POST['request'])) {

            echo $counter;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I tried a lot of different ways and read a lot of posts but somehow nothing worked for me.
Hope someone got an idea.

Comment: What is the progress bar for? As you noticed this approach will not work; the actual solution depends on what the process is that you're waiting for.

Comment: I'm going to fetch a lot of data the next days trough an API. Over 9000 entries with a lot of data and of course I don't want to bombard my server neither the API server. So I want to insert some breaks in the code especial an request limit of 10 per 5sec and I thought that it would be grat to have a prpgress bar.

Comment: You can make a script that specifically counts the progress and call that periodically. For example if you save data to a database, have the script count the rows in the table. If you save it to a file/files, have it count lines or the amount of files. etc etc

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. I think I will take the way with the database. I think this will be the simpliest way to save data for a progress bar with my knowlege

Answer (score -1):

Take a good look at your "echo $counter;" part in your PHP script, that's in a (5000 times) loop.

Comment: I did... I guess I don't get your point. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Isn't the function doing the following:
`sleep;
echo 1;
sleep;
echo 2;
sleep:
echo 3;
`
So essencially, you've build a very slow function that echo's 123456789101112.... etc

Answer (score -1):

> After the PHP code is interpreted and executed, the web server sends resulting output to its client, usually in form of a part of the generated web page – for example, PHP code can generate a web page's HTML code

From PHP's wiki page

This basically means that the whole php file will always be executed before returning the output. The loop will be executed 5000 times before returning the output.

Comment: Alright! Didn't knew that at all. I guess that means that I can't get the current loop number?

Comment: Unfortunately yes that's what it means.